# Installing Coax & Cat6 in 2-Gang with Electrical?

Tags: electrical, wiring, data-wiring, coax, interference

Using a 2-gang box, can I install a (1) outlet, (2) coax, and (3) Cat-6 line without code or interference issues?

I have an existing 1-gang box with electrical that I am running the coax and cat-6 towards. The new lines don't follow the electrical line, but I am unsure if having all the outlets so close may also cause interference or code issues.

Is it okay to put them all in the same box?

Comment: They sell dividers that should slide into the double gang box, to separate electric from data. Common practice is do keep data and electric in separate stud bays.

Comment: No electrical inspector I've worked with allows a mix high and low voltage in a single gang box unless the device in the box needs both (eg. Some thermostats).  I've also never seen a UL listed divider.  That would be required to comply with most electrical code regulators' requirements.  The safe route is to keep low voltage out of high voltage boxes.  You generally don't even need a box for low voltage by code.

Comment: I believe it's a code violation and I know it's **Not A Good Idea**

Comment: Not an electrician, but 2002 National Electrical Code, Section 800-52 (a)(1)(c) Exception No. 1 allows electrical conductors to share an outlet box when the conductors and communications cables are separated by a barrier within the box. Google "dual voltage electrical box" -- they have the dividers at my local big box. Your local code may vary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you *can*, as long as you keep the conductors separated. However, you should likely avoid it if possible. Common practice is to keep power and communications circuits in separate stud bays.

National Electrical Code allows you to put power and communication circuits in the same box, as long as all the conductors are separated by a permanent barrier or listed device.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 8 Communications Systems
>
> #### Article 800 Communications Circuits
>
> **800.133 Installation of Communications Wires, Cables,
>   and Equipment.**
>
> **(A) Separation from Other Conductors.**
>
> **(1) In Raceways, Cable Trays, Boxes, Cables, Enclosures and Cable Routing Assemblies.**
>
> **(d) Electric Light, Power, Class 1, Non–Power-Limited
>   Fire Alarm, and Medium-Power Network-Powered Broadband
>   Communications Circuits in Raceways, Compartments,
>   and Boxes.** Communications conductors shall not be placed in
>   any raceway, compartment, outlet box, junction box, or similar
>   fitting with conductors of electric light, power, Class 1, non–
>   power-limited fire alarm, or medium-power network-powered
>   broadband communications circuits.
>
> ***Exception No. 1:*** Where all of the conductors of electric
>   light, power, Class 1, non–power-limited fire alarm, and
>   medium-power network-powered broadband communications
>   circuits are separated from all of the conductors of communications
>   circuits by a permanent barrier or listed divider.

Here's an example of a listed device:

From a [Carlon sales brochure](http://www.carlonsales.com/techinfo/brochures/electrical/Zip%20Boxes_2B1.pdf)

> [image: Carlon Low Voltage Divider Plate]

Comment: I used one like from Home Depot https://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-2-Gang-Old-Work-PVC-Dual-Voltage-Box-Bracket-Case-of-12-E-18-4-DVR/202668377 (they sell single ones in the store but only 12 packs online) after seeing this answer since the dividers were too large for the boxes they had in stock.